# Could not install Istio demo profile. Error: Could not configure logs

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, istio

I have installed Minikube on my laptop. I am trying to run the Istio. I have followed the instructions given here.
https://istio.io/docs/setup/getting-started/

My setup is as below.

- Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
- Minikube version 1.5.2
- Kubernetes version 1.16.2
- Istio version 1.4

When I run the command as given in the documentation

```
  istioctl manifest apply --set profile=demo
```

It fails immediately giving below error.

> Could not configure logs: couldn't open sink "/dev/null": open
>   /dev/null: The system cannot find the path specified.

Anybody has faced the issue? Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Did you download and install istioctl like mentionted [there](https://gist.github.com/VidyasagarMSC/2dcb760297f97220fb5e24621c606d76)?

Comment: I used istioctl-1.4.0-win.zip from
 https://github.com/istio/istio/releases

Comment: i have just installed and configured 1.5.1, is it required for you  to use 1.4 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding flag --logtostderr.

```
istioctl manifest apply --set profile=demo --logtostderr
```

Comment: This did generate a big log.  - Failed to generate and apply manifests, error: failed to generate manifest: failed to create Istio control plane with spec: ...  _<some more lines>_ .. error: chart metadata (Chart.yaml) missing

Comment: Yes, I had that issue too today, after that first problem. In the end, I followed the instructions at https://istio.io/docs/setup/install/helm/ to get it working that way for now (noting that this other method will be deprecated in future). Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try helm and update here.

Comment: In case it is any help, I used Helm version 2.16.1 - worked great following the instructions at the link.

Comment: I also followed the deprecated Helm install and it worked as far as my local dev evaluation is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

I checked istio github and there is same [issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/19020) reported 3 days ago.

As i could read there

> The issue is windows specific,should be fixed in 1.4.1 release in about 2 weeks

For now i would suggest to use helm instead of istioctl, like @lain mentioned in his answer.

**EDIT**

There is workaround for istio 1.4.0 provided in github link above

> Finally got my hands on a windows machine. Workaround for 1.4.0(folder from the Istio release archive):

```
istioctl manifest apply --set profile=demo --logtostderr --set installPackagePath=install/kubernetes/operator/charts
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Also, thanks for pointing to istio github issue. I tried to search earlier but could not find. Yes, I will use the alternative suggested by @lain.